# Read file appears the same even after it is changed js

Tags: javascript

I have a function that reads a file, but even once you change the data it returns the same output in chrome. the only way I have found to correct this is to clear cache and site data. is there any way where if the file is changed it would change the output without clearing site data in between each run?

```
   function readTextFile(file)
        {
            fetch(file)
            .then(response => response.text())
            .then(text => console.log(text))
        }
```

Comment: a reload must happen to update the files data. If you don't want to reload the whole page I suggest using an Iframe and reload the iframe to update the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from -seriously

a reload must happen to update the files data. If you don't want to reload the whole page I suggest using an Iframe and reload the iframe to update the data